# parseInt returns Not a Number (NaN)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I made an IDE (with `<textarea>` and CodeMirror), which looks like this:

[image]

And on the left, there is a `div` containing the lines counter.

So what I'm trying to do is to get the last line number (12 in the picture above).
This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(document).keydown(function() {
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror-linenumber");
        element = element.item(element.length - 1);
        escape(element);
        let num = "";
        num = parseInt(element);
        console.log(num);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="array.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
        <script>
            var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
                  mode: "xml",
                  htmlMode: true,
                  lineNumbers: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I run it on Chrome, it gives me an output `"NaN"`.
[image]
I know that this question is already asked, but I didn't find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for you to use [`escape(element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape). In fact, it is deprecated anyway. What you're doing is simply encoding the element into some kind of hexadecimal string, which you do not want.

What you want is to simply access the `innerText` property of the element, and use either `parseInt(element.innerText)` or even better, the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), `+element.innerText` to get the line number:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(document).keydown(function() {
        let element = document.getElementsByClassName("CodeMirror-linenumber");
        element = element.item(element.length - 1);
        console.log(+element.innerText);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="array.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
        <script>
            var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
                  mode: "xml",
                  htmlMode: true,
                  lineNumbers: true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```